# Can't figure out how to correct my array?

Tags: c#, arrays

Here is my code. I get a red line under StockPrices saying that it can not implicitly convert type decimal to int. Which I understand since StockPrices Array is set as a decimal. I can't figure out how to convert it. (If you find any other issues, please call it out. I'm still learning!)

```
public int FindNumTimesNegativePriceChange()
{
        int difference = 0;
        decimal[] negativeChange = new decimal[StockPrices];

        for (int i = 0; i < StockPrices.Length - 1; ++i)
        {
            difference = (int)(StockPrices[i + 1] - StockPrices[i]);

            if (difference < 0)
            {
                negativeChange++;
            }
        }

        return negativeChange;
```

Currently no result is returned.

Comment: In your code, `negativeChange` is an array of decimals, and you wrote `negativeChange++`. The latter equals to `negativeChange = negativeChange + 1`. That is why you get the error `can not implicitly convert type decimal to int`. And the part `decimal[] negativeChange = new decimal[StockPrices];` should probably be `decimal[] negativeChange = new decimal[StockPrices.Length];`.

Comment: How do I fix the negativeChange++? I want to store the number of times there is a negative change and then return that number

Comment: If you want just to count how many negative changes you detect in the StockPrices array you don't need an array of negativeChange. You could just have an integer that increments at each detection

Comment: Could you outline how to do that?

Comment: Just remove the array declaration for negativeChange and initialize it like _int negativeChange = 0;_ no other changes are needed

Answer (score 1):

If you want a new array with the same length as an existing array, use the `Length` property for the source array, not the array itself:

```
new decimal[StockPrices.Length];
```

But I'm not sure that is what you are looking for at all.
You want a counter, so `difference` only needs to be an `int` in this case.

The next issue is that you are explicitly casting `decimal` values to an `int` which means you will lose precision. Other data types would throw an exception in this case but `decimal` allows it and will *truncate* the values, not round them.

> For stock prices, commonly the changes are less than 1, so in this business domain precision is usually important.

If it is your intention to only count whole integer losses then you should include a comment in the code, mainly because explicit casting like this is a common code mistake, comments are a great way to prevent future code reviewers from editing your logic to correct what *looks* like a mistake.

- Depending on your source code management practises, it can be a good idea to include a reference to the documentation / task / change request that is the authority for this logic.

```
public int FindNumTimesNegativePriceChange()
{
    int difference = 0;
    int negativeChange = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < StockPrices.Length - 1; ++i)
    {
        // #11032: Only counting whole dollar changes
        difference = (int)(StockPrices[i + 1] - StockPrices[i]);

        if (difference < 0)
        {
            negativeChange++;
        }
    }

    return negativeChange;
}
```

A final peer review item, this method processes a single input, but currently that input needs to be managed outside of the scope of this method. In this case `StockPrices` must be declared at the member level, but this logic is easier to isolate and test if you refactor it to pass through the *source array*:

```
public int FindNumTimesNegativePriceChange(decimal[] stockPrices)
{
    decimal difference = 0;
    int negativeChange = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < stockPrices.Length - 1; ++i)
    {
        difference = stockPrices[i + 1] - stockPrices[i];

        if (difference < 0)
        {
            negativeChange++;
        }
    }

    return negativeChange;
}
```

*This version also computes the difference (delta) as a decimal*
Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XAyFnm